# Chain multiple RTC alarms: good or bad practice

Tags: arduino, interrupt, real-time-clock

Working on a SAMD Arduino, I found myself in need for multiple alarms, triggering events at interrupt time.

Most people suggest `TimeAlarm.h`, which is a library to schedule timers and alarms with the `Time.h` library. Unfortunately the alarms don't run on interrupt time.

Instead of adding Time and TimeAlarms libraries I came up with "daisychaining" RTC alarms. I am wondering if this is good or bad practice. Could such a thing bite back?

A snapshot of the code:

```
void main() {
    ...
    //set alarm at 16:0:0 and trigger Event_1 at interrupt time
    rtc.enableAlarm(16,0,0);
    rtc.attachInterrupt(Event_1_isr);
    ...
}

void Event_1_isr() {
    ...some code...
    //Set next alarm and interrupt Event_2
    rtc.setAlarmTime(16, 0, 15);
    rtc.enableAlarm(rtc.MATCH_HHMMSS);
    rtc.detachInterrupt();
    rtc.attachInterrupt(Event_2_isr);
}

void Event_2_isr() {
    ...some code...
    //I guess you get the point
    rtc.setAlarmTime(16, 0, 30);
    rtc.enableAlarm(rtc.MATCH_HHMMSS);
    rtc.detachInterrupt();
    rtc.attachInterrupt(Event_3_isr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to get in and out of the interrupts as fast as possible. I think that's nearly always good advice.

You ask "could such a think bite back" - yes, in maintenance headaches. Your logic and settings are scattered throughout the code.

I would consider turning it around: make one or two routines responsible for setting up and handling the RTC interrupts. Let it use a table of times and routines to set the correct delay and dispatch the appropriate action. Then you don't need the overhead of attach/detach-interrupts, all the relevant code is in one place, and your data tells you what to do.